# Connect Sencha Touch with (GXT or GWT)

Tags: java, gwt, extjs, sencha-touch, gxt

I've built GXT app using MVC model, but i have to build mobile client using Sencha Touch, how could i benefit from GXT or GWT java code in the first project ? should i choose to have some sort of [RESTFUL webservice like described here](http://blog.eliranmalka.com/post/41809258265/gwt-applications-as-rest-clients-handling-json), or should i use Sencha io ? or write entirely dedicated server side for the mobile ?

any recommandations or experiences in this subject are welcomed.

Comment: You might want to consider waiting for GXT 4.0, as it is going to introduce a full tablet support for GXT: http://www.sencha.com/blog/gxt-roadmap-update

Comment: yes, GXT 4.0 gonna support tablets, but i need to make mobile app right now, i cannot wait for 4.0